# Cómo reemplazar por NA todos los valores de todas las columnas?

Tags: r, data

Tengo un df del tipo

```
ID_estacion Temp  Humedad   Presion 

C001        25     56         65
C002        32     -9999      22 
C003        28     65         -9999
C004        -9999  32         -9999
```

El df original tiene 30 parámetros metereológicos que contienen varios -9999. Debo cambiar dichos valores por NA, y lo he estado haciendo usando:

```
df$Tem[df$Tem == "-9999"] <- "NA"
df$Humedad[df$Humedad == "-9999"] <- "NA"
df$Presion[df$Presion == "-9999"] <- "NA"
```

Quisiera hacerlo de una forma más rápida para evitar escribir una línea para cada parámetro ¿Cómo lo hago?.

He intentado

```
library (dplyr)

df <- mutate_all(df, funs(replace(., .=='-9999', NA)))
```

Pero me muestra el error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: character
>   string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Supongo que se debe al formato que tienen las variables, pues al hacer un `str(df)`, veo que `ID_estación` es un caracter, mientras que el resto de variables son numéricas.

Qué debería hacer?

Answer (score 3):

```
df[df == "-9999"] <- "NA"
```

Al no usar el operador `$` busca dentro de toda la estructura de datos. Cuando encuentra asigna **la cadena de caracteres** `"NA"`. Si lo que quieres es asignar el valor lógico `NA` deberías usar:

```
df[df == "-9999"] <- NA
```

> Advertencia: al operar sobre *toda* la estructura de datos podría modificar valores que no quieres modificar. Usar con mucho cuidado y validar el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas compañero te paso una función simple y el uso de sapply (dyplyr) para que puedas implementarla y cambiar los NA de tu df por el valor que quieras:

#Con esta función cambio los NA por ceros

cambio_na = function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,x}

df_sin_na=data.frame(sapply(df,cambio_na))